# Linkbucks Adware on Goo.gl links

Tags: dns, malware, adware, url-shortening

I have created a goo.gl shortlink for my app page, so that I can know how many times the link is clicked from my page. I checked the link when I created it, and it worked fine.

Now when I checked it again, it redirects to some linkbucks ad (though I have Ad block plus, dunno how much it works on linkbucks). Linkbucks is anyways banned in my country so it never redirects.

The shortlink which I made - `http://goo.gl/Wv66yg`

The original URL was - `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noob.hammerinc`

and the redirection url is - `http://linkbucks.com/ns1B/url/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noob.hammerinc`

I can see this issue in multiple PCs and this is happening only for certain shortlinks.

Now it might be because I am using common router for all these PC (Couldn't check with other network.)

I searched on Google groups and found that it was a [Google DNS issue earlier](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/emnc1hRhp8Q), but the post is marked as solved.

Is there any way I can fix this issue? Is it really a problem with my Router/PC/Network?

Can you please check if it's showing linkbucks at your end too (Please be aware since I am not sure if it's safe to open the shortlink or not)

**Update:**
The problem is with my Router/net connection. I've switched to another ISP which has separate router and the problem is gone. But my old connection is still infected. Anything to resolve it without loosing the settings? I don't remember the compromised router's settings and might not be able to reinstate it later.

Comment: You tried change DNS? You can test url using anonymizer or something like [this](http://netrenderer.com).

Comment: @crazypotato Please check my update. It's basically a problem with my router.